# Variance of this probability density

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

I have the function $\rho(x) = \frac{sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ and I want to calculate its variance on $\mathbb{R}$. Does anybody know how to do this? Cause afaik the integral does not converge.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the variance of $\rho(X)=\frac{\sin^2 X}{X^2}$, where $X$ is a random variable. If so, you need to specify the distribution of $X$. Or maybe you have a random variable with density function $k\rho(x)$ for suitable $k$, Then the variance of $X$ does not exist.

Comment: i do not understand it? the distribution is given by rho and the variable is X. what is left?

Comment: If the "density" is $\rho(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a problem, since I think $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(x)\,dx=\pi$. The integral is not $1$, so we don't have a density function. This can be adjusted for by using $\frac{1}{\pi}\rho(x)$. If that's the density function of $X$, over all reals, then the variance does not exist. By the way, the mean does not exist either.

Comment: I would put that in an answer @Andre, maybe with added explanation of the values / divergence of the zeroth, first, and second moments of the distribution given by the density function $ p(x) = \frac{\sin^2x}{\pi x^2} $.

Comment: This is known as the $Sinc^2$ distribution (with the inclusion of the constant $\frac{1}{\pi}$ ... which was missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was clarified in a comment that $\rho(x)$ is supposed to be the density function of a random variable $X$, presumably defined over all of $\mathbb{R}$. (If it is only for positive reals, that makes little difference to the analysis.)

The density function cannot be quite $\rho(x)$, since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx=\pi$. But if we replace $\rho(x)$ by $\frac{\rho(x)}{\pi}$, we do get a density function.

The second moment of $X$ about the origin does not exist, for
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \frac{\sin^2 x}{\pi x^2}\,dx$$
diverges. The divergence is easy to prove.

Indeed, $E(X)$ does not exist either.